# Canadian citizen traveling to USA and what other documents besides passport are required?

Tags: usa, paperwork, canadian-citizens

What other identification is required besides a passport when travelling to the USA from Canada? Also is a criminal records check done in Canada sufficient for noncriminal entry into usa?

Comment: the answer depends on your reason for traveling there. Tourism? To attend university? To start a new job? To look for a job? Marry a resident? Please edit a few more details into your question.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are applying for a long stay visa (student, work, etc) there are no criminal background checks needed to visit the USA. When you arrive at the border, CBP will run your passport number through their system and as long as you are not on any watch lists or weren't a bad kid on a previous visit to the USA, entry is quick and simple.